# SQL Server - Group Records Like Archives By Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table Fixture with three fields.

```
ID | Fixture | Date
-------------------------
1  | 123456  |  20110515
2  | 123446  |  20110512
3  | 123476  |  20110411
4  | 123486  |  20110310
```

...and so on.

I need to group the records by date and want to get fixture counts.

Results would display like the following example. How can I achieve the results from SQL Query?

```
Archives

February 2011 (3)
January 2011 (6)
December 2010 (10)
November 2010 (7)
October 2010 (5)
```

I need community help to solve this issue, kindly help me out.

Comment: What have you tried?  And what is the data type for the `date` column - DATE/DATETIME or VARCHAR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it, it has month numbers, you can update it in your code or in sql

```
 select COUNT(id), DATEPART(year, dtCreated) as y, DATEPART(MONTH,dtCreated) as mo 
    from TaxesSteps group by DATEPART(year, dtCreated), DATEPART(MONTH,dtCreated)
    order by 2 desc, 3 desc
```

Comment: Just curious - does this produce the result set requested?

Comment: I found the exact results from your answer, but all the members helped me out to solve the issue. I specially thankful to @astander as he responded my comments more times. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Fixture INT,
        Date DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,123456,'20110515' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,123446,'20110512' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3,123476,'20110411' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 4,123486,'20110310'

;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  DATENAME(month,Date) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(year,Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) DateValue,
                ID,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), Date, 112) OrderValue 
        FROM    @Table
)
SELECT  DateValue,
        COUNT(ID) Cnt
FROM    Vals
GROUP BY    DateValue,
            OrderValue
ORDER BY    OrderValue
```

Comment: Can I order the date by descending order? for instance I am getting the results by your query like this 

**October 2010 (2105)
June 2011 182
June 2010 389
October 2011 152**

Can I show the results like;

**October 2011 152
June 2011 182
October 2010 2105
June 2010 389**

Comment: I mean can I show the results in descending order by date? DateValue should start by May 2011, April 2011 and March 2011

Comment: Have a look now, does this help?

Comment: @astander I want to use order by statement to order the data by descending order, but not working. Your statement solves my problem by 80% and I am happy to get the quick action by stackoverflow community. Thanks to all and specially you dear.

Comment: Then just change *ORDER BY OrderValue* to *ORDER BY OrderValue DESC*

Comment: ORDER BY OrderValue does not work for me. Because I have to use ORDER BY with DateValue, in my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this code will do what you require:

```
SELECT
    DATENAME(m, [Date]) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR([Date]) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS ArchiveMonth
    ,COUNT(ID) AS Items
FROM
    Fixture
GROUP BY
    DATENAME(m, [Date]) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR([Date]) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

(dang it... already beaten)

Comment: I did not find the correct results, but it is near the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @table table (ID bigint identity(1,1), Fixture nvarchar(100), [Date] nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO @table values ('123456','20110515')
INSERT INTO @table values ('123256','20110410')
INSERT INTO @table values ('123356','20110511')
INSERT INTO @table values ('122456','20110503')

--select DATEPART(month,0, (cast([date],datetime) from @table
SELECT DATENAME(month, CAST([Date] as datetime))+ ' ' + DATENAME(Year,CAST([Date] as datetime)) + ' (' + CAST(COUNT(Fixture) as varchar(100)) + ') '
from @table
group by DATENAME(month, CAST([Date] as datetime))+ ' ' + DATENAME(Year,CAST([Date] as datetime))
```

Comment: Not find my answers, but all the answers I received are relevant and do not completely focus on my question. I need the results like 

ORDER BY Year DESC,  Month DESC

Answer (score 1):

I give you **three options**, with 3 outputs as displayed

#### Option #1

```
select   convert(char(6), Date, 112) MonthYear, count(*) CountFixtures
from     Fixture
group by convert(char(6), Date, 112)
order by convert(char(6), Date, 112)
```

Output #1 - the most basic. The front end can work out the month and year names:

```
MonthYear CountFixtures
--------- -------------
201103    1
201104    1
201105    2
```

---

#### Option #2

```
select   datename(month, convert(datetime,convert(char(6), Date, 112)+'01'))
         + ' '
         + left(convert(char(6), Date, 112),4) MonthYear,
         count(*) CountFixtures
from     Fixture
group by convert(char(6), Date, 112)
order by convert(char(6), Date, 112)
```

Output #2 - recommended. Count and dates are separate fields

```
MonthYear                           CountFixtures
----------------------------------- -------------
March 2011                          1
April 2011                          1
May 2011                            2
```

---

#### Option #3

```
select   datename(month, convert(datetime,convert(char(6), Date, 112)+'01'))
         + ' '
         + left(convert(char(6), Date, 112),4)
         + ' ('
         + convert(varchar,count(*))
         + ')' FixturesByMonth
from     Fixture
group by convert(char(6), Date, 112)
order by convert(char(6), Date, 112)
```

Output #3 - **exactly** as you have in the question, with brackets. However, I strongly believe formatting (brackets et al) is a front end task, not SQL Server side.

```
FixturesByMonth
----------------
March 2011 (1)
April 2011 (1)
May 2011 (2)
```

Comment: Note: The SQL above works even if Date is a VARCHAR column, as long as it ALWAYS contain a valid date YYYYMMDD.